# Is there a non-Electron based 100% open source wallet for Linux

Tags: wallets, linux

I have tried nearly all desktop wallets, they are either based on Electron which does not run great on a Raspberry Pi with X11 Forwarding or don't seem to be open source, some have at least some propriety code which I don't want to trust my coins to, Ether is open source so should the wallet. A QT based wallet like DOGE has would be great. Even a CLI based wallet would perfect.